# advice on mongodb structure with sensors implantation and data

Tags: mongodb

I work on a project with many sensors in a building, and each sensor send data.

Each sensor have information like: uuid_sensors, equipment, location, technical limit, ...

And each sensor have data: value, date, uuid_data

I made two collections: one for implantation and one for data

This is the first time I use a nosql database. Is it a good choice for this use? Is this the right strategy?

I ask this question because after I want to get data of a room, a floor, and the building. So I do many request on my database

Kind regards

Romain

Comment: what do you mean by `collection for implementation`?

Comment: I made a english mistake. It's not implementation but implantation (uuid_sensors, equipment, location, technical limit, ...)

Answer (score 0):

The effectiveness of schema depends on usage much. So you should write out basic scenario lines and list the queries you're going to make over the data set. This may lead to organizing data in a different way compared to what you're thought before.

For example, the schema can become room-centric. The top level documents will represent a room, `floor` and `building` will be attributes. Room will contain list of data from censors. Or it can become censor-centric. And data can contain `room`, `floor` etc as attributes. You can have two types of top collections: rooms and censors and bind them using ids.

However if you find yourself going deep in such approach and have complicated queries that reference multiple entity types at a time it can be an indication that a relational database engine fits your problem better

Comment: Thank you for your response. If I do room-centric with data inside I'm afraid to have too much data and so have too big document. In fact there are about 20 sensors per room, and each sensor send about 10 values per minutes